# chrome options being overwritten

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

When using selenium python bindings with undetected-chromedriver, after setting chrome options, namely user-data-dir, it gets overwritten by extra chrome options that are automatically added not by me. this results in the user-data-dir being different from what i specified in my script.
Environment details:

```
ubuntu:latest
Python 3.10.12
selenium==4.12.0
undetected_chromedriver==3.5.3
Google Chrome   116.0.5845.140 (Official Build) (64-bit) 
ChromeDriver 116.0.5845.96
```

```
from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

self.user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--user-agent=" + self.user_agent)
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1280x720")
self.driver:Chrome = Chrome(
options=options,
user_data_dir=self.sessionFolderPath,
        )
```

when i check `chrome://version/` under `command line`, I get:

```
/bin/google-chrome
 --user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
 --no-sandbox
 --disable-dev-shm-usage
 --disable-gpu
 --window-size=1280x720 #what i set
 --remote-debugging-host=127.0.0.1
 --remote-debugging-port=54671
 --user-data-dir=sessions/test2 #what i set
 --lang=en-US
 --no-default-browser-check
 --no-first-run
 --no-sandbox
 --test-type
 --window-size=1920,1080 #what i get
 --start-maximized 
 --no-sandbox 
 --log-level=0
 --user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/google-chrome #what i get
 --flag-switches-begin 
 --flag-switches-end --origin-trial-disabled-features=WebGPU
```

as you can see there are some repeated entries which results in my `window-size` and `user-data-dir` being overwritten by what seems to be defaults by the chromedriver. However, the expected behaviour is that my options will overwrite the defaults not vice versa. Any help will be greatly appreciated :)